# HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException when trying to test handling of HTTP POST

Tags: spring, unit-testing, http, spring-mvc

I am trying to test `POST` method in spring framework but I keep getting errors all the time.

I first tried this test:

```
this.mockMvc.perform(post("/rest/tests").
                            param("id", "10").
                            param("width","25")
                            )
                .andDo(MockMvcResultHandlers.print())
                .andExpect(status().isOk());
```

and got the following error:

`org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException`

Then I tried to modify the test as below:

```
this.mockMvc.perform(post("/rest/tests/").
                            content("{\"id\":10,\"width\":1000}"))
                .andDo(MockMvcResultHandlers.print())
                .andExpect(status().isOk());
```

But got the following error:
                 `org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException`

My controller is:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/rest/tests")
public class TestController {

    @Autowired
    private ITestService testService;

    @RequestMapping(value="", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.OK)
    public void add(@RequestBody Test test)
    {
        testService.save(test);
    }
}
```

Where `Test` class has two field members: `id` and `width`. In a few word I am unable to set the parameters for the controller.

What's the proper way to set the parameters?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should add a content type `MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON` to the post request, e.g.

```
this.mockMvc.perform(post("/rest/tests/")
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .content("{\"id\":10,\"width\":1000}"))
                .andDo(MockMvcResultHandlers.print())
                .andExpect(status().isOk());
```