# MockMvc Test Spring throws org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException

Tags: spring, unit-testing, mockmvc

I am getting the follow exception org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException trying to test a Json Controller.

The method in controller is:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/report", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
    public @ResponseBody DatosJsonVO report(@RequestHeader(value = "hash", required = true) String hash,
            @RequestBody ReportVO report) {
}
```

My test method is the following:

```
@Test
    public void reportarPreguntaSesionInvalida() throws Exception { 
        ReportVO report = new ReportVO();
        report.setIdQuestion(1);
        report.setIssue("Wrong answer");
        mockMvc.perform(put("/json/report").header("hash", "123456789")
                .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).content(asJsonString(report))).andDo(print())
                .andExpect(content().string("{\"code\":2,\"message\":\"Session error\",\"data\":null}"));
    }
```

But, I get this response:

```
MockHttpServletRequest:
         HTTP Method = PUT
         Request URI = /json/report
          Parameters = {}
             Headers = {hash=[8.16615469E8], Accept=[application/json]}
             Handler:
                Type = com.controller.json.QuestionsJsonController
               Async:
   Was async started = false
        Async result = null
  Resolved Exception:
                Type = org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException
        ModelAndView:
           View name = null
                View = null
               Model = null
            FlashMap:
MockHttpServletResponse:
              Status = 415
       Error message = null
             Headers = {}
        Content type = null
                Body = 
       Forwarded URL = null
      Redirected URL = null
             Cookies = []
```

My Spring Version is 4.0.0.RELEASE

Comment: Answered here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31609496/httpmediatypenotsupportedexception-when-trying-to-test-handling-of-http-post

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException when trying to test handling of HTTP POST](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31609496/httpmediatypenotsupportedexception-when-trying-to-test-handling-of-http-post)

Answer (score 4):

You need to set the content type.

```
 mockMvc.perform(put("/json/report")
.header("hash", "123456789")
.accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
.contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
.content(asJsonString(report))).andDo(print())
.andExpect(content().string("{\"code\":2,\"message\":\"Session error\",\"data\":null}"));
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution, I am having similar issue and by adding .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE), solved the problem for me

Answer (score -1):

```
        mockMvc.perform(put("/json/report").header("hash", "123456789")
            .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .content(asJsonString(report)))
            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .andDo(print())
            .andExpect(content().string("{\"code\":2,\"message\":\"Session error\",\"data\":null}"));
```

Comment: Could you please give some detail to your code, especially since it's so unreadable? Also, include your code in back ticks \`like this\` to display them `like this` so that it's readable. Alternatively, you can use four spaces prior to your line to render as code, which is helpful for multi-line code.